# Can someone tell me how to make an image inside a canvas move?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Can someone tell me how to make the image on the canvas move? In a previous version of the game I made the image was a div so it moved just fine but I can't figure this out. It is making me write more so please ignore this part:

```js
//this is the variable for the image i want to move
var blinky = {
x: 0,
y: 0
};






//this makes the image only appear when the page is loaded
var byReady = false;
var byImage = new Image();
byImage.onload = function(){
 byReady = true;
};

byImage.src = "blinky.jpg"





//this puts the images on the canvas
var render = function(){
if(bgReady){
ctx.drawImage(bgImage,0,0);
}

if(hrReady){
ctx.drawImage(hrImage,hero.x, hero.y);
}

if(emReady){
ctx.drawImage(emImage,monster.x, monster.y);
}

if(byReady){
 ctx.drawImage(byImage,blinky.x,blinky.y);
}







//this moves a div around the screen randomly
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();
    
});

function makeNewPosition(){
    
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 30;
    var w = $(window).width() - 30;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('#blinky').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    
    $('#blinky').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });
    
};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
    
    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
    
    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a draw loop (using `requestAnimationFrame`) that draws the image on the context of the canvas.

Here is a full jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ety656yq/